# How to extract Morphological Features and Color features from the "bound-box" [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

I'm Developing Grain Quality Identification MATLAB Application. I preprocessed the images and Now I have problem in feature extraction phase ,

Here these are the Morphological Features and Color features that I want to extract from "bound-box"

Morphological Features

```
 1. Area for each Object

 2. Major Axis Length of each bound box

 3. Minor Axis Length of each bound box

 4. Aspect Ratio
```

Color features

```
1. Red Mean 
2. Green Mean
3. Blue Mean
```

This is what I coded upto now

```
% Get the orginal image & show 
[fileName, pathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg;*.tif;*.png;*.gif','Select the Picture file');
I = fullfile(pathName, fileName);
I = imread(I);
% imshow(I)


% selected rice image Background subtraction 
% Use Morphological Opening to Estimate the Background
background = imopen(I,strel('disk',7));
I2 = I - background;
% figure, imshow(I2);

% get the Black and white Image 
% output image BW replaces all pixels in the input image with luminance greater than 0.17 level 
BW = im2bw(I2,0.15);
% figure, imshow(BW)

% Remove small objects fewer than 30 pixels from binary image
 pure = bwareaopen(BW,30);
% figure, imshow(pure)


% Visualize the individual objects
% figure, imshow(out)
% cc = bwconncomp(out)

% Blobs analysis , This cell of codes find all the objects on the image, and find the properties of each object. 
[Ilabel num] = bwlabel(pure); 
disp(num); 
Iprops = regionprops(Ilabel); 
Ibox = [Iprops.BoundingBox]; 
Ibox = reshape(Ibox,[4 num]); 
imshow(I) 

% Plot the Object Location ,This cell of codes plot the object locations. 
hold on; 
for cnt = 1:num 
rectangle('position',Ibox(:,cnt),'edgecolor','r'); 
end
```

I just want to extract above 7 features from bound box, I'm really appreciate the way that I want to follow for above purpose or any resource .

Thank You for Your Time!

Comment: (1) Area: Simply sum up all of the pixels that are white within the bounding box. (2),(3) Major and Minor axis length can be found by the largest and smallest of the width and height respectively of your bounding box.  (4) Aspect Ratio: max of (width / height) and (height / width) of the bounding box. (5), (6), (7): Mean of Red, Green and Blue channels is self explanatory.  Simply decompose each channel within the bounding box and find the mean of each channel.